# Question about shacharit/ma'ariv at home (ashkenazi)

Tags: tefilla, blessing, maariv

I'm somewhat new to practicing Judaism in my daily life, and don't live anywhere near a minyan that I could daven shacharit and ma'ariv with (outside of shabbat). I know that a lot of people cut certain parts out from the siddur when they're praying by themselves at home, but I'm curious what people consider the most important parts. I think modeh ani when waking, al netilat yadaim, putting on the tallit, pesukei d'zimra (do folks tend to do all of them? or just a selection, if at all?), shema/v'ahavta, amidah, aleinu -- seems like a good selection. Obviously ma'ariv would cut out the bits before pesukei d'zimra. I want to incorporate more prayer into my daily practice! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Definitely consult a rabbi first, because such selection shouldn't be at random. It's clear that saying the Shema (in the morning in tallit and tefillin for men) is a Biblical command, so you should definitely start with that and its blessings, and with the Amidah they form the core of our prayers. Regarding other parts there may be some flexibility, as you're learning and aren't familiar with them yet, but in most cases there's a religious obligation to say them.

Comment: I was in a similar position when I started doing teshuva, @countthrashula, you can find my email on my profile page, I'd be happy to walk you through it